# ExtJS5 icons in paging toolbar are not visible

Tags: css, extjs, pagingtoolbar

I am using extjs 5.0.

I have added a paging toolbar to my grid with the following code inside grid's initComponent
(Also tried it as a config property)

```
this.bbar= [{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            store: 'MyApp.store.fares.SummaryRemote',
            displayInfo: true
        }];
```

The icons in the toolbar are not visible in the UI. But the icons are actually there. As seen in the below screenshot.If i mouse hover the component, i can see the tooltip and also do click.

[image]

I inspected the dom and couldn't find any issues. Do you have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Did you click on the image links in the inspector to see if you have the images in the right folder?

Comment: I had this problem too, I had to do a sencha app build again through cmd to get the css to correct.

Comment: hmm.. i have to try that.. as of now i am using the below css to make it work. .x-tbar-page-next, .x-tbar-page-last, .x-tbar-page-first, .x-tbar-page-prev, .x-tbar-loading{
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: table-cell;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 line-height: 0;
}